# Create a function in Kotlin that takes an enum parameter

Tags: kotlin

I'm creating a function that takes an enum value as a parameter, but I am very new to Kotlin and I can't find any material that covers this specifically.

Example:

```
enum class Color(val rgb: Int) {
        RED(0xFF0000),
        ORANGE(0xffa500),
        YELLOW(0xffff00),
        GREEN(0x00FF00),
        BLUE(0x0000FF),
        INDIGO(0x4b0082),
        VIOLET(0x8F5E99)
}
fun getHexColor (Color: Enum)
{
    when(x){
        Color.BLUE -> println("Battle")
        else -> print("otherwise")
    }

}
```

I get an error that says:

```
One type argument expected for class Enum<E: Enum<E>>
```

I've looked through Kotlin documentation for over an hour and I've got nothing to show for it... do any of you have an idea of how to use this class as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enum creates a new class so you can use it as function argument type, as shown below.
For functions in kotlin see [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html).

```
fun getHexColor (x : Color)
{
    when(x){
        Color.BLUE -> println("Battle")
        else -> print("otherwise")
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh thank god, had no idea that's how enum classes can be used. Works perfectly thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the type which is `Color`:

```
fun getHexColor (x: Color) {
    when(x){
        Color.BLUE -> println("Battle")
        else -> print("otherwise")
    }
}
```

Note that a function prefixed with "get" should return something. Since when is an expression you can do it like this:

```
fun getHexColor (x: Color) = when(x) { // will return a String
        Color.BLUE -> "Battle"
        else -> "otherwise"
}

println(getHexColor(Color.BLUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Enum is actually special kind of class (it is even called `enum class`). So, use it as normal class and use benefits you get from it.

Example:

```
enum class X {
    X, Y
}

fun check(param: X) {
    val unit = when (param) {
        X.X -> println("x")
        X.Y -> println('y')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are able to do it like this with an interface for example:

```
enum class Color(val rgb: Int): IHexColor {

    RED(0xFF0000){
        override fun getHexColor() = rgb.toString()
    },
    GREEN(0x00FF00){
        override fun getHexColor(): String = rgb.toString()
    },
    BLUE(0x0000FF){
        override fun getHexColor(): String = rgb.toString()
    }
}

interface IHexColor {
    fun getHexColor(): String
}

@Test
fun testBasic() {
    val red = Color.RED
    val green = Color.GREEN
    val blue = Color.BLUE

    val palette = arrayListOf(red, green, blue)

    palette.forEach {
        println("Color: $it :: hex - ${it.getHexColor()}")
    }
}

// output => Color: RED :: hex - 16711680, Color: GREEN :: hex - 65280, Color: BLUE :: hex - 255
```

How to use enum class:

```
fun useColorClass(color: Color){
    println(color.rgb)
}

@Test
fun testColor() {
    useColorClass(Color.RED)
    useColorClass(Color.BLUE)
    useColorClass(Color.GREEN)
}

// output => 16711680, 255, 65280
```

**An answer for your question:**

```
fun getHexColor (c: Color): String {
   return when(x){
        Color.BLUE -> println("Battle")
        else -> print("otherwise")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A function syntax in Kotlin looks like this:

```
fun double(x: Int): Int {
    return 2 * x
}
```

where `x` is the name of the function parameter of type `Int`. Your function is not valid since you use `Color` as the parameter name rather than its type. To fix it do:

```
fun getHexColor (color: Color) {
    when(color){
        Color.BLUE -> println("Battle")
        else -> print("otherwise")
    }
}
```